# Can't save edited values in asp.net gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview

I have a web page with a gridview. I click the edit button and  programmatically fill 2 fields, Reviewdate(current date) and user(current user). When I click the update button the data in these two fields is not save in the SQL table.

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="ReviewDate" SortExpression="ReviewDate" >
<EditItemTemplate> 
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" dataformatstring="{0:d}"    Text='<%  # GetDate()%>'></asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" dataformatstring="{0:d}" Text='<%# Bind("ReviewDate")%>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Reviewer" SortExpression="Reviewer">
<EditItemTemplate>
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server"  Text='<%# GetUser)% '>
</asp:TextBox>
</EditItemTemplate>
<ItemTemplate>
<asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("Reviewer") %>'></asp:Label>
</ItemTemplate>
<asp:TemplateField>
```

I tried using the RowDataBound event with no success

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowDataBound(sender As Object, e As  GridViewRowEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowDataBound
If e.Row.RowType = DataControlRowType.DataRow Then
  If e.Row.RowState = DataControlRowState.Edit Then
       Dim txtreviewDate As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("ReviewDate"), TextBox)
      txtreviewDate.Text = GetDate()
      Dim txtUser As TextBox = DirectCast(e.Row.FindControl("Reviewer"), TextBox)
      txtUser.Text = GetUser()
  End If
```

End If
   End Sub}

I also tried using the RowUpDating event again with no success. This time the control could not be found (Null exception error.

```
Private Sub GridView1_RowUpdating(sender As Object, e As  GridViewUpdateEventArgs) Handles GridView1.RowUpdating
Try
 Dim con As New SqlConnection(ConnectionString)
 Dim row As GridViewRow = DirectCast(GridView1.Rows(e.RowIndex), GridViewRow)
 Dim id As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("SMasterID"), TextBox) 'Int32.Parse(GridView1.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value.ToString())
 Dim tdate As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("ReviewDate"), TextBox)
 Dim tname As TextBox = DirectCast(row.FindControl("Reviewer"), TextBox)
 Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("update SMasterCurrentYear set Reviewer= '" + @reviewer + "',ReviewDate= " + @ReviewDate+ " where SMasterID =@id", con)
 GridView1.EditIndex = -1
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = id
 cmd.Parameters.Add("@reviewer", SqlDbType.VarChar, 30).Value = tname.Text      cmd.Parameters.Add("@ReviewDate", SqlDbType.Date).Value = tdate.Text 
 con.Open()
 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
 con.Close()
 bind()
 Catch ex As Exception
   Throw New Exception(ex.Message)
 End Try
End Sub
```

I don't know what to do at this point. 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Did you check Page.IsPostback on page load event when you bind the gridview?